# How to assign an integer array to a Arrayadapter in android

Tags: android

**Purpose**

I have 3 spinners for date of birth input; so I need to load values to this, I need to add 200 years so its better to use an integer array and assign this to a array-adapter and set this to a spinner;
I worked-out the following code but I cant assign an integer array to a array-adapter; which is the best way to implement this; I appreciate if any one can help.

```
int yeararray[]=new int[300];

year=(Spinner)findViewById(gami.Numerology.R.id.yearinput);

for(int i=1800;i<=2020;i++)
{
    yeararray[i]=i;
}

ArrayAdapter <Integer> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>( this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,yeararray );

year.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Comment: It may be better to impliment a costum Adapter rather than using ArrayAdaptr.

Comment: use an Integer[] rather than an int[]

Answer (score 7):

Try this code:

```
ArrayAdapter <Integer> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>( this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,yeararray );
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    year.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Comment: @Rick forget `dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);`

Answer (score 0):

```
Integer[] int_numbers = new Integer[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

Double[] double_numbers= new Double[]{1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0,9.0,10.0};


ArrayAdapter <Integer> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>( this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,int_numbers );

ArrayAdapter <Double> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Double>( this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,double_numbers);
```